# Why fully connected neural network cannot learn to count

Tags: neural-networks, lstm

I am writing some educational material, and I am actually trying to find some proof for something. Consider the following case: you generate random vectors of length (let's say 20) containing only 0 and 1.

I have developed and tested succesfully LSTM that can easily learn to count the number of 1 in each vector.

Now I know that a standard fully connected neural network (let's say one layer with 15 neurons) cannot learn this. Can someone point me to a proof (at least an intuitive one). I have my intuitive understanding, but would love to see something more.

Comment: The standard network - we are talking about a network with a size 20 input, size 15 hidden layer, size 1 output layer here, or did I misunderstand?

Comment: Yes it is correct.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What should I do when my neural network doesn't learn?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/352036/what-should-i-do-when-my-neural-network-doesnt-learn)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's break it down to an extreme case - **one neuron, linear activation** - and build up from there.

You assign a static (once trained) weight to each index. Now, if you only used it on a single training case, you'd get the right answer quite easily - just assign a weight of 1 to each index where there's a one and zero to zeros.

Your layer performs a sum operation on the activations, passes it on to the output with a weight of 1 for the whole thing, and since your values are binary, you get the correct number of ones... for this specific case.

Now you try to apply it to a new random vector with the exact same amount of ones. And it fails catastrophically - the positions of ones and zeros shifted, but the weights remain fixed to the **indices** of the input.

---

But hey, your output layer can handle more than one input - let's add more neurons to solve the problem! But... each of those neurons has the exact same limitation - it can only output one accurate prediction per permutation.

By adjusting the layer weights at the output layer, you get a model that effectively learns the error rate of each memorized permutation and uses that rate to construct an **approximation of Adaboost**.

Given enough neurons, you may be able to **brute-force** your way into a somewhat close approximation, but the model will never figure out that there is an underlying algorithm to exploit.

As such, it would **fail to generalize** to a case where your random number generator started generating slighly skewed distributions of values for the vectors - the model memorized the error rate for the original distribution, which no longer holds true.

Even if you use a nonlinear activation on the output layer, at best you can only attenuate the influence of very weak classifiers for a slightly better prediction. The activation on the hidden layer doesn't really matter here, since it's connected directly to a binary input with no inherent structure so there's only two possibly true activation states - hitting all-ones, or all-zeros.

This is a XOR-like problem, so a single layer on its own quite simply won't ever find an actually decent solution - that you can find an approximation at all is all thanks to the output layers having its own set of weights.

---

Both LSTM and simply adding another hidden layer will address this issue simply by introducing more neuron layers - each layer being in a way a discrete step in an algorithm - and thus empowering the network to make a smarter representation. For LSTM, the network presumably tends to learn to remember a running tally, but it's just a slice of the space of possible solutions - with enough depth, you could arrive at some quite exotic ones.